# How to add a ContextMenu depending on which WPF DataGrid row is right-clicked?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu, row, right-click

I need to display different options in a ContextMenu depending on which row of a WPF DataGrid is right-clicked.  My initial ideas were to accomplish this through either binding or handling a mouse click event, but I haven't had success with either strategy so far.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Thank you!

Denise

Answer (score 4):

You can handle the DataGrid's ContextMenuOpening event and based on the original source of the routed event you adjust your context menu.

Below is a sample where I show a context menu if the data context of the original source is of type Inventory otherwise I do not show the context menu by handling the event.

```
Private Sub InventoriesDataGrid_ContextMenuOpening( _
    ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs) Handles _
    InventoriesDataGrid.ContextMenuOpening

    Dim context = DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, System.Windows.FrameworkElement).DataContext

    If TypeOf context Is Inventory Then
        InventoriesDataGrid.ContextMenu = InventoriesDataGrid.Resources("DefaultContextMenu")
    Else
        e.Handled = True 'Do not show context menu.
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm sure it is too late to help you now, but in case it is not too late and for anyone else who comes across this.

Comment: I agree totally with what CStick did... we're almost doing the same here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the OriginalSource from the ContextMenuEventArgs argument in the ContextMenuOpening event :

```
DataGridResults.ContextMenuOpening += (sender, args) =>
{
    var frameworkElement = args.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
    var gridRow = frameworkElement != null ? frameworkElement.TemplatedParent as DataGridRow : null;
}
```

Note however that the use of TemplatedParent depends on how the datagrid items were bound